# Array ListBox Populating only the last option

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am hoping one of my fellow vba enthusiasts can assist. I have 2 combo boxes in a userform. In the first Listbox I am looking to select a LOB (Line of Business). With this in the corresponding box I am looking to bring in a list of Names. I have a table on a sheet which has a repeating value for the LOB and in the column to the right of this all the names I would like to populate in the next box. The issue I am getting is, the combo box I am attempting to fill is always populated with the final value and for the rest of the values coming in as blank. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub CBLOB_Change()

Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrProdFam As Variant
Dim mysearch As String
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idx As Long
Dim Searchrange As Range
    
    If Me.CBLOB.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        mysearch = Me.CBLOB.Value
    
        With Sheets("Lookups")
            Set Searchrange = Sheets("Lookups").Range("N2", .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With
    
        arrData = Searchrange.Resize(, 3).Value
    
        ReDim arrProdFam(1 To UBound(arrData, 1))
        
        For idx = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
            If arrData(idx, 1) = mysearch Then
                Me.CBProdFam = arrData(idx, 2)
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrProdFam(cnt) = arrData(idx, 3)
            End If
        Next idx
        
        If cnt > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrProdFam(1 To cnt)
            Me.CBProdFam.List = arrProdFam
        Else
            MsgBox "Uh oh, things have gone a little sideways and the LOB " & mysearch & " cannot be located. Please try another Option!"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a LOB to search for!"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrap the above. As soon as I posted it I seen I had typed `arrProdFam(cnt) = arrData(idx, 3)`and it should have been `arrProdFam(cnt) = arrData(idx, 2)`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an addendum as an answer.